# d3.axis.ticks() will be ignored

Tags: d3.js

I can't skip x-axis labels with this code:

```
    // define x-axis data
var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, this.width]).padding(0.2)
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));

// store the x-axis element
var xAxis = this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(10)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")));
```

ticks(d3.timeDay.every(10) seems to be ignored. I got always the whole bunch of labels specified by the data.

Comment: `d3.timeDay` must be used with a **time** scale. You have a band scale.

Comment: How can I skip tick labels in a band scale?

Comment: It depends on how do you want to skip them.